# Re-serving a sites javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I would like to dynamically load a javascript file and undo what was done with the static javascript i have on my site. the static javascript i want to edit is
`document.getElementsByTagName('script')[3]`this is what im trying to do: 
`document.getElementsByTagName('script')[3].attributes[2].value = "http://differentlocation.com/jsfile.js"`
The thing is when the source is altered I want all the other functions i had statically cached to go away. how is this possible?

*reworded. The sites current javascript attaches event handlers and does all kinds of functions,  i would like to make all of these go away. Basically I am reloading a Almost exact copy of the javascript and dont want certain handlers active. etc
Or is there a way to blank out all of the pages current javascript, Just make it all useless, and then Load my new javascript

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  Would you please try rephrasing?  Specifically, please clarify "undo what was done with the static javascript" and " I want all the other functions i had statically cached to go away".  Do you want to run the entire script again?  In what way is "source is altered"?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I updated the description of my question. Thank you

Comment: If it is indeed your site then why don't you just change the source to point to your new script? 
I'm pretty sure there is no way to unload the javascript that was already loaded and attached to events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to get the JavaScript to run again, most likely: it needs to be linked (which jsFiddle doesn't allow).  Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2Nkp/1/).

In this example, we have three buttons.

```
<button id="myButton">Add an event listener for the bellow</button>
<button id="listener">Do something</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

We can then add event listeners,

```
// Do some stuff
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("listener").addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("I do something!");
    });
});
```

... and at some point, reset the page.  This works by taking the current HTML content out of the page, and having it stored in a variable.  We then put it back in, causing all bindings to elements to be removed.  It also has the harmful side effect of not running inline scripts.

```
// Soft reload of the page
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not using jQuery. If you were, this simple line of code should remove all event handlers from every element in your document:

```
$("*").off();
```

It might be worth exploring.